# error boundary in React doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-error-boundary

I used `react-error-boundary` to implement `<ErrorBoundary>` by wraping it around the component that may throw an error

```js
export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const handleReset = () => setQuery("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setQuery(e.target.value);
        }}
      />

      <FormErrorBoundary onReset={handleReset} resetKeys={[query]}>
        <Form query={query} />
      </FormErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}

function Form({ query }) {
  if (query === "error") throw new Error("foo");

  return <p>{query}</p>;
}

function FormErrorBoundary(props) {
  return <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallBack} {...props} />;
}

function ErrorFallBack({ error, resetErrorBoundary }) {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      There was an error
      <pre>{error.message}</pre>
      <button onClick={resetErrorBoundary}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the idea is that when we type `error` in the input field the `Form` component should throw an error and the error boundary is supposed to catch it and display an UI with an re-try button

However if I type `error` in the input field, the app would still crash. Check out this screenshot. [image]

Only after you click on `x` to close it, you can see the error boundary is working and there is the retry button you can click on. But I thought the error boundary would prevent it from crashing. Did I implement it wrong or this is the expected behavior for error boundaries in React?

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/error-boundary-bz2ir?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

If your are in development mode you will see the error stack always. If you get a production mode app version if a error is launched you will see only the error boundary. (If all is ok)